# What does the following C++ marked code does?

Tags: c++11, struct

I wonder what does the line which marked "**This line**" means and what happens to P(struct) after this operation?

```cpp
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    struct P
    {
      int x,d,u,val ;
    }a[10];
    int main()
    {
      int n ; scanf("%d",&n) ;
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
        int x1,y1,x2,y2 ;
        scanf("%d%d%d%d",&x1,&x2,&y1,&y2) ;
        **a[1]=(P){x1,y1,y2-1,1} ;** // <--- This Line
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like it is trying to fill second array element by a constant struct, but do not think it works.

Comment: The line constructs a temporary instance of `P`, from individual components; then copies it into `a[1]` element of the array.

Comment: But why it doesn't output anything when I add printf("%d%d%d%d",a[1].x,a[1].d,a[1].u,a[1].val); before return 0; ?